# Create Dendrogram using plotly

Tags: python, plotly

I am trying to plot a dendrogram using plotly. I used the code given below:

```
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.figure_factory as ff

names = list(result_data['merchant_id'])

dendro = ff.create_dendrogram(new_data,labels=names)
dendro['layout'].update({'width':1400, 'height':600})
plotly.offline.iplot(dendro, filename='simple_dendrogram')
```

and I got the plot :
[image]

How I can Assign title, x label and y label in above plot?

Answer (score 2):

You can just update the layout with the required settings, Refer the below example.

**Code:**

```
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.figure_factory as ff

names = list(result_data['merchant_id'])

dendro = ff.create_dendrogram(new_data,labels=names)
dendro['layout'].update({'width':1400, 'height':600, 'title': 'this is the title', 
                    'xaxis': {'title': 'xaxis label'}, 'yaxis': {'title': 'yaxis label'}})
plotly.offline.iplot(dendro, filename='simple_dendrogram')
```

Comment: @neha does this help?